# What correlation exists between the assumptions $a)$ and $b)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ small. Consider the two assumptions:
$$a)\quad F(s)\ge \frac{1}{s^2}\quad\mbox{ for $0<s<\varepsilon$};$$
$$b)\quad sF^{\prime}(s)\ge \frac{1}{s}\quad\mbox{ for $0<s<\varepsilon$}.$$

As an exercise, I need to understand which is stronger between them; I mean, if $a)\implies b)$ or $b)\implies a)$. Or, in general, what kind of relation exists between them.

I tried this: conditions $b)$ is equivalent to $F^{\prime}(s)\ge \frac{1}{s^2}$ for $0<s<\varepsilon$. Thus
$$\int_s^{\varepsilon} F^{\prime}(v) dv \ge\int_s^{\varepsilon}\frac{1}{v^2} dv\iff F(\varepsilon)-F(s)\ge \frac{1}{s} -\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\iff F(s)\le C-\frac{1}{s},$$
for a suitable constant $C>0$.
Apparently, I do not see any relation beteween them.

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong? Or please give some hints?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no implication between $a)$ and $b)$. Here are counterexamples to both implications :

- the function $F : s \mapsto \dfrac{1}{s^2}$ obviously satisfies $a)$, but one has $F'(s) = - \dfrac{2}{s^3}$ which takes negative values, so $F$ does not satisfy $b)$.
- conversely, the function $F : s \mapsto -\dfrac{1}{s}$ does not satisfy $a)$ because it takes negative values for $s > 0$, but one has $F'(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2}$ do $F$ satisfies $b)$.